# Restart/ReInit a servlet

Tags: servlets, jboss, restart

I want to restart a servlet (declared in web.xml, when JBoss is running) simply because its init-param points to a file which content has changed (i.e. providers.fac below has been modified).

If there is a way to reload the init-param without restarting the servlet, it will be good too.

I suppose I can modify the servlet to add a request param and function to restart itself ?
Is there any other option?

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>coverage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coverageServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ConfigUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>file:///C:/coverage/providers.fac</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>CacheDir</param-name>
        <param-value>coverage</param-value>
    </init-param>         
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Environment:
Servlet Api 2.4
JBoss 4.2
Spring Framework 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. Add an extra check on `doGet()` or `doPost()` which reloads the file when a certain request parameter is been set while an admin user is logged in and provide an admin screen which invokes that request.
2. Rewrite the servlet (or refactor the part to `ServletContextListener`) to store it in `ServletContext` instead of as an instance variable of the servlet and have some admin screen which reloads the file in `ServletContext`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in jboss you can simply restart a servlet by altering the web.xml file if your servlet is exploded. On linux a touch would do.

Not sure what format your config file is but if you are trying to reload automatically a property configuration file I would have a look at the commons configuration lib that supports this out of the box([FileChangedReloadingStrategy](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/reloading/FileChangedReloadingStrategy.html))

Comment: thanks, i'll try FilechangedReloadingStrategy since manual restart is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to restart your servlet automatically and many many times in a day/week you should make sure your permgen is good enough to handle the servlet reloads. There were instances where I had done this in production and burnt myself down with a lot of PermGen errors.

Comment: Did you restart just one servlet or all of them? Yes I have seen some PermGen errors when I redeploy *.war manually many times

Comment: @portoalet It was one servlet but was a Controller servlet doing all the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

I would separate these concerns by pulling the file management out of the servlet and putting it into a JBoss JMX ServiceMBean. The MBean can take care of watching the file for changes and reloading when necessary, and can also expose the required operations [to the calling servlet]. This will allow you not to have to reload and re-init the servlet (or the WAR) which are fairly heavyweight operations.

I will invent a couple of operations for the FileManager:

```
public interface FileManagerMBean extends org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean {
   public void setFileName(String fileName);
   public void setCheckFrequency(long freq);
   public String getCoverageData(......);
   public String getProviderData(......);
}
```

The implementation might be  (in the same package please :) )

```
public class FileManager extends org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport implements FileManagerMBean  {
   public void setFileName(String fileName) { .... }
   public void setCheckFrequency(long freq) { .... }
   public String getCoverageData(......) {  /* impl */ }
   public String getProviderData(......) {  /* impl */ }
   public void startService() throws Exception {
       /* Start a file watcher thread */
   }
   public void stopService() throws Exception {
       /* Stop the file watcher thread */
   }

}
```

Your servlet might look like this:

```
// A ref to the MBean
FileManagerMBean fileMgr = null;
// The JMX MBean's ObjectName
ObjectName fileMgrOn = org.jboss.mx.util.ObjectNameFactory.create("portoalet.com:service=FileManager");

public void init() {
   // Get the JBoss MBeanServer
   MBeanServer server = org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
   // Create an MBeanInvoker for the service
   fileMgr = (FileManagerMBean)javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(server, fileMgrOn,FileManagerMBean.class, false);    
}
```

Now you can use the **fileMgr** instance to make calls to your FileManager MBean, which should be thread safe unless you synchronize access to **fileMgr**.

I realize this looks a bit over-engineered, but you really should separate the functions of the servlet from the functions of managing the file.